# How to set text background color without spilling past text

Tags: html, css, background-color

**I want to:**

1. be able to style some text on my HTML page so that a certain background color only covers the text and not beyond it.
2. Ideally I would like to control this from one div.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsccheng/x060fyms/2/) of the below:

```css
#edit_this_div {
  min-width: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#bad_way {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="edit_this_div">Please edit this div to there isn't extra yellow background without manually setting the width.</div>
<br>
<div id="bad_way">This is the inefficient and manual way.</div>
```

**What I tried:**
The way I thought of accomplishing this is to set the div as an inline block, which I've also shown in my jsfiddle. However, I rather not do this because I feel it would complicate things; when I did this my block started jumping around and combining with other elements. I don't plan to have any other elements with the div so I am fine with it staying as a block that takes up the whole line on the screen.

With the display of block, I also tried setting the padding and minimum widths but it doesn't have an effect laterally for removing the extra color that spills past the text.

Comment: do you want to do this using `CSS` only? I guess there would be good solutions using `jQuery` / `Javascript`.

Comment: Hi @northkildonan thanks for reading. Yes it is with HTML/CSS only, the other answers provided here actually worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally recommended that you put text into appropriate block tags, i.e. `<p>...</p>`, `<h1>...</h1>`, `<blockquote>...</blockquote>`, etc.

If you did that, it would be easy, for example:

```
<div id="edit_this_div">
    <p>Please edit this div to there isn't extra yellow background without manually setting the width.</p>
</div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
#edit_this_div p {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
}
```

Even cleaner would be to use both `<p>`-tags as well as additional inline tags, for example `<span>`-tags:

```
<div id="edit_this_div">
    <p><span>Please edit this div to there isn't extra yellow background without manually setting the width.</span></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#edit_this_div p span {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `<mark></mark>` tag, like this:

```
<p>Do not forget to buy <mark>milk</mark> today.</p>
```

Here's a fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/am9rzfmd/

The default css settings for this tag are:

```
mark {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
```

So you don't have to explicitly define the css, only just in case you need to change the color.

**Update**
As [misterManSam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2930477/mistermansam) pointed out:

> Be aware that the  element has a special semantic meaning and
>   shouldn't be used if you just want "to make my text a yellow
>   background"

Comment: Be aware that the `<mark>` element has [a special semantic meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) and shouldn't be used if you just want "to make my text a yellow background". Depending on your content, you may want to use `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<i>`, `<b>` or `<span>`

Comment: @misterManSam thank you for pointing that out. I was assuming a user **is** willing to give the highlighted text special semantic meaning from the beginning, that's why I suggested `<mark>` tag. Because, you know, why else to highlight the text?

Comment: @Nordenheim - fair enough :) It's a good idea to provide a reference from a reputable source such as w3.org or developer.mozilla.org which gives a (usually) clear indication of the elements intended purpose.

Comment: @misterManSam and Nordenheim, Thanks for your care in your answers and editing my question to a I'm assuming more acceptable form in the SO community. I've been seeing this mention of semantic meaning and at first I'm like, why does it matter as long as we get the output we need to the person viewing the html page? However, it looks like it is more for the developer and others reading the code to better understand the intent of the formatting. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Change it from a div to a span and it will only stretch its width to the contents within it.

```
<body>
    <span id="edit_this_div">Please edit this div to there isn't extra yellow background without manually setting the width.</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="bad_way">This is the inefficient and manual way.</span>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbv5ryhk/